# cron job to remove old data from postgres on debian

Tags: postgresql, debian, cron

I need to create a cron that runs every night and remove some of the data (older ones) from my database. I am running postgres on debian. How do I do that? My server is tomcat6. Does anyone have a step by step instruction including script to do that?

Answer (score 3):

in most cases, I prefer a shell script with an here-document. (shell-variables expand nicely in here-documents):

```
#!/bin/sh
PSQL=/local/postgres/bin/psql
SOME_VALUE=123

$PSQL my_database <<THE_END
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE my_column <= $SOME_VALUE
    ;
THE_END
```

Answer (score 2):

Several good ways.
You may want to do more than just one `DELETE`. Run `ANALYZE tbl`? Handle multiple tables?
I would wrap the work in a a plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.f_maintain()
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _msg    text := 'Report';
    _min_ts timestamp := now()::timestamp - interval '5y'; -- max. age 5 years
    _count  int;
BEGIN

DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE  my_ts < _min_ts
AND    <some condition>;

GET DIAGNOSTICS _count = ROW_COUNT;

IF _count > 0 THEN
    _msg := _msg || E'\nDeleted rows in tbl: ' || _count;
END IF;

ANALYZE tbl;

-- more ?

RAISE LOG '%', _msg;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

... and call it from the shell like this:

```
psql -p 5432 event -c 'SELECT myschema.f_maintain()'
```

Schedule a cron job for the system user postgres:

```
crontab -e
```

To run it every day at 02:06, add a line like:

```
06 02 * * * psql -p 5432 event -c 'SELECT myschema.f_maintain()' >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a direct call to psql right in /etc/crontab. The call would follow this pattern:

```
psql -c 'DELETE FROM my_table WHERE ...'
```

You would need to supply the appropriate additional arguments to 'psql' to create the database connection. See the [documentation for psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) for more information about that.