# Export data from table to CSV file using \copy - psql

Tags: database, bash, postgresql, psql

I have a bash script which connects to postgres database (version 9.5) and run copy command to generate CSV files. It's working without any issue.

```
pg-source-query() {
    psql --quiet "$DATABASE_SOURCE_URL" <<< $'\set ON_ERROR_STOP true \n'"$1"
}
sql_stm="\copy (SELECT * FROM <table_name>) to '<file_path>' with csv"
pg-target-query "$sql_stm"
```

Now I need to run the same select command with *SET* like below.

`sql_stm="\copy (SET "request.user_id" = <user_id>); SELECT * FROM <table_name> to 'C:\tmp\persons_client.csv' with csv"`

Now I'm getting an error.
***ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SET"***

I'm just wondering why I cant run **SET** inside **/ Copy(....)**.

Or am I doing anything wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Use a here-document, and most of your quoting problems will vanish. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251168/905902

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Finally I found the answer.

```
sql_stm="(SET "request.user_id" = <user_id>); \copy SELECT * FROM <table_name> to 'C:\tmp\persons_client.csv' with csv"
```

Did the trick!