# How to add double quotes in table names using postgresql query?

Tags: postgresql

i have migrated the table and schema from oracle to postgresql. schema name and table name both contains double quotes. How to select the table name in the specific schema using psql command i.e

```
psql -U enterprisedb -d test -c "select count(*) from "HISTORY"."EMP";"
```

I have tried the following methods:-

```
psql -U enterprisedb -d test -c "select count(*) from "HISTORY"."EMP";"
psql -U enterprisedb -d test -c "select count(*) from "||HISTORY||"."||EMP||";"
psql -U enterprisedb -d test -c "select count(*) from ""HISTORY"".""EMP"";"
```

Below are the codes which i have tried:-

```
psql -U enterprisedb -d test -c "select count(*) from "HISTORY"."EMP";"
psql -U enterprisedb -d test -c "select count(*) from "||HISTORY||"."||EMP||";"
psql -U enterprisedb -d test -c "select count(*) from ""HISTORY"".""EMP"";"
```

i want psql command to fetch the data .when i am using double quotes its coudln't find the table . How to use the double quotes in the psql command.
I can fetch the data while login to the server the select queries works. but i want to use psql command to work and fetch details.

Comment: Try a backslash in front of the quote.

Comment: Use a here-document to avoid most of your quoting/escaping pains: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250590/cron-job-to-remove-old-data-from-postgres-on-debian/11251168#11251168

Comment: Have tried using single quotes like `psql -U enterprisedb -d test -c "select count(*) from 'HISTORY'.'EMP';"` ?

Comment: BTW: do your table names *contain* quotes, or do you use the quotes to handle the (silly) ALL-CAPS table names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a here document, which preserves all quotes:

---

```
#!/bin/sh
psql -U enterprisedb -d test <<ZZZZ
        select count(*) from "HISTORY"."EMP"
        ;
ZZZZ
```

Comment: psql -U enterprisedb -d test -c 'select count(*) from "HISTORY"."EMP";' use the single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: That will get difficult if your query needs single quotes as well as double quotes.

Comment: if both needed then query needs to be modified as well. as for now my requirement meets.